# Word meaning of the "so" and "that"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

1. It wasn't so easy.
2. It wasn't that easy.

Is there any difference in the above sentences? Can "so" and "that" be used with adjectives without comparison degree such as "correct", "optimum", etc?

Comment: Adding the word *that* points out that it wasn't as easy as *one would think/expect (the degree of easiness is somewhat predicted)*. Adding *so* does not **bind** anyone with their thought of the degree of easiness. It's in general. *"I also want to do paragliding as **you did.**" "Ah, it's not **that** easy!"* "I want to climb Everest!", "It's not **so** easy, give up that idea!"

Comment: The two flavors you describe are close enough that they are interchangeable, however, if you don't emphasize the word that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one puzzled me for a fair while today, but I've come up with a couple of conclusions. Firstly, their definitions are nigh on indistinguishable.

> [So (adv) 3. To a great extent; to such an evident degree: But the idea is so obvious.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/so)
>
> [That (adv) 1. To such an extent or degree: Is your problem that complicated?](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/that)

So I got thinking of some examples where only one or the other is correct.

> I had a load of exams today. The Maths one was **so** easy.

"That" could not be used here.

However, if we change the sentence to be negative, we can use both.

> I had a load of exams today. The Maths one wasn't **so/that** hard.

In my British English, I prefer using "that", as I feel (but couldn't find any evidence) that "so + adjective" stems from the longer phrase: "so + adjective + that + clause" e.g. "He was so drunk that he passed out."

To give you an idea of best practice: the two are fairly interchangeable, but "that" is preferred in situations where there is previous reference to what you're describing (see my first example). "So" is the option to use, in short exclamations:

> That was **so** interesting!

Comment: thank you, JMB. I knew they both are (adverbs) with the role of adjective intensifiers, but, I thought (I wasn’t sure) that “so” cannot be used with extreme adjectives. Now that I have your explanation everything is crystal clear to me.